# How to find html/script file on server or magento admin

Tags: static-block, block-html

I have a magento 1.9 e-com site - furnituretrader.com.au - and I want to change the url link to a section at the bottom, however I can't locate the html section on the admin panel or the file server - how do I use a tool to locate this html to edit? [image]

Comment: It’s probably contained in a CMS static block. Have you checked them?

Comment: try to search footer in cms block admin then check it might be footer_links or search with contact in cms block

Answer (score 0):

you can location footer block at below mentioned path

app/design/frontend/*/*/template/page/html/footer.phtml

- is your theme vendor 
  */* is name of your theme inside theme vendor folder .

Once try and let me know your feedback.

Thanks!

Comment: One ref: http://www.magento.cc/how-to-edit-the-magento-footer-area.html

Comment: Thanks Ramesh - you were indeed correct, I have since corrected this footer page - thanks